# accidentally moved and fixed /bin/ directory, but now can't su

Tags: linux, permissions

I accidentally moved my `/bin` directory to `/usr/bin/bin`, anyway, I managed to move it back to its place with

```
# /usr/bin/bin/mkdir /bin
# /usr/bin/bin/mv /usr/bin/bin /
```

and then I was able to login as root, but I wasn't able to `su` from my user, it gave me an authentication error. I ran `chmod +s /bin/su` and `chmod u+s /bin/su` as root, and it fixed it.

another thing I noticed is that I can't `ping` either; it gives me this error:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.1
ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted
```

and this is my ping file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 44K Jun 30 20:38 /bin/ping
```

I guess I messed up all the permissions and SGID on my `/bin` folder. Is there any way to fix this? (other than formatting)

Just for the record, I'm using a 64 bit Debian 8.

Comment: How did you actually break `/bin`? Just moving it wouldn't have destroyed setuid features on files it contained. Without this information it's going to be very tricky to help you restore it again.

Comment: I don't know!! I just accidentally moved it to `/usr/bin`, and then fixed it by moving it back... i am as confused as you :S is there any way to restore the permissions the way it was? it is an almost clean linux install, since I installed it yesterday.

Comment: At least, did you use `mv`, `cp`, `tar`…?↵(the missing return)
The `ping` problem has no relation with your `/bin` war maneuvers: its mode, owner & group are correct.

Comment: I just used `mv`, as root... I wanted to install a self-made script, so I used `cp my-script /bin/`, it didn't work, so I attempted to move it to `/usr/bin`, but I accidentally my whole /bin/ into `/usr/bin/`, then I realised I forgot to add execute privileges to my script... and I feel like a moron now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would debootstrap a base system to another directory.

```
debootstrap --variant=minbase --arch=amd64 jessie /tmp/bootstrap http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/
```

Then copy all files from /tmp/bootstrap/bin to /bin keeping the permissions.

```
cp -a /tmp/bootstrap/bin/* /bin/
```

Now many (and the basic ones) of your files in /bin should be ok and you should be able to see which were not touched using the timestamp (old files can have wrong permissions).

For the rest you can use

```
apt-get install --reinstall PACKAGE
```

to set the permissions back.

You can find the package to a file with

```
dpkg -S /path/to/file
```

This is even scriptable...

Good luck!

Comment: I was about to suggest a solution like [this one](http://serverfault.com/questions/221447/how-to-repair-restore-ubuntu-10-04-after-sudo-chmod-777) but yours is easier (particularly as it's just `/bin` to be fixed).

Comment: Thats nice. Didn't know that! And I am not sure, whether mine really is easier. Yours is just one script. And you could add a check, so only files in /bin are reseted.

Comment: that's a very elegant answer!! it worked like a charm... i ran a `cp -r -a /tmp/bootstrap/bin/* /bin/` just to be sure... thanks a lot!